# Masm DLL procedure inside for loop

Tags: c++, dll, masm

I wrote a MASM procedure and loaded it dynamically into my C++ application. 
I keep calling it within a for loop but at a certain point it just changes the iterator for the loop and everything crashes.

Loop code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
    if (useAsm){
        if (0 <= i && i <= 15){//F
            F = FFunc(res[1],res[2],res[3]);
            g = i;
        }
        else if (16 <= i && i <= 31){//G
            F = GFunc(res[1], res[2], res[3]);
            g = ((5 * i + 1) & 0x0F);
        }
        else if (32 <= i & i <= 47){//H
            F = HFunc(res[1], res[2], res[3]);
            g = ((3 * i + 5) & 0x0F);
        }
        else if (48 <= i & i <= 63){//I
            F = IFunc(res[1], res[2], res[3]);
            g = ((7 * i) & 0x0F);
        }
    }
}
```

i gets changed at `F = GFunc(res[1], res[2], res[3]);` when i is 24

This is the code of the MASM procedure

```
GFunc proc  Bval: DWORD,
        Cval: DWORD,
        Dval: DWORD
mov eax, Cval
xor eax, Bval
and eax, Dval
xor eax, Cval
ret
```

FFunc works just fine so I don't really understand why this is happening.

I checked the disassembly:

```
call        dword ptr [GFunc]  
add         esp,0Ch
```

`add  esp,0Ch` seems to be overwriting i somehow, at least that's what the debugger tells me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the C++ compiler believes that your assembly function follows the [cdecl calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl), but your assembly function most likely follows the stdcall convention.

One way of fixing this would be to change the declaration of `GFunc` to something like:

```
extern DWORD __stdcall GFunc(DWORD, DWORD, DWORD);
```

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't think of that